# MySQL Subquery error: SQLSTATE[42S21]:

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm using Yii 1.1.15 and am getting this a duplicate column name in my query using `scopes` in my model

```
function scopes () {
     return array(
          'isUsed'=> array(
                    'alias' => 'd',
                    'join' => 'JOIN `ads` v',
                    'condition'=>'d.is_new="0"',
                    //'group'=>'v.store_id'
            ),
     );
}
```

it generates this query

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
        SELECT * FROM `store` d 
        JOIN `ads` v 
        WHERE ((d.pending!="1") AND (d.is_new="0")) AND (v.store_id IN (6))
    ) sq
```

Yii give me this error

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'id'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
        SELECT * FROM `store` d 
        JOIN `ads` v 
        WHERE ((d.pending!="1") AND (d.is_new="0")) AND (v.store_id IN (6))
    ) sq
```

any idea who to fix this? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about your case may be select will help !! Add  'select'=> 'd.*,v.*'

Comment: Seeing as you're only counting rows, a static `SELECT` value would also work, eg `SELECT 1`

Comment: @vijay4vijju getting the same error

Comment: @vijay4vijju `CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'id'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT d.*,v.*  ....... `

Comment: @vijay4vijju nevermind, added only the fields i needed to the `select` and it worked. Thanks for the hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of columns ambiguous in your sub query. 
You should use specific columns name instead of * in your sub query.

Please refer to below example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
        SELECT d.columnName,v.columnName,.... FROM `store` d 
        JOIN `ads` v 
        WHERE ((d.pending!="1") AND (d.is_new="0")) AND (v.store_id IN (6))
    ) sq
```